# printing two adjacent values returned from adjacent_find

Tags: c++, stl

I want to print the first 2 values where the next is doubled from the current value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool doubled (int x, int y) { return x*2 == y; }

int main()
{
  deque<int> di;
  deque<int>::iterator diiter;

  for (int i=0; i<=10; i+=2) di.insert(di.end(), i);

  for (diiter = di.begin(); diiter != di.end(); ++diiter)
    cout << *diiter << " ";
  cout << endl;

  diiter = adjacent_find(di.begin(), di.end(), doubled);
  if (diiter != di.end()) {
    cout << "found " << *diiter << " at " << distance(di.begin(), diiter)+1 
         << " and " << *(++diiter) << " at " << distance(di.begin(), diiter)+1 
         << endl;
  }
}
```

the output is

```
0 2 4 6 8 10 
found 4 at 3 and 4 at 2
```

not what I expected, which should be:

```
0 2 4 6 8 10 
found 2 at 2 and 4 at 3
```

What's wrong with my code? I don't understand how the second position is decremented from the first one when I actually incremented it.
Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program is giving strange results because it does not take in to account the fact, that order of evaluation of arguments to a function(In this case operator <<) is **Unspecified**.

My Answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006569/c-pass-by-reference-variable-not-being-update-on-the-same-line-on-which-functi/7006623#7006623)**, explains the problem in detail & should be a good read.

You need to `cout` them on separate statements.

```
 cout << "found " << *diiter;
 cout << " at " << distance(di.begin(), diiter)+1;
 cout << " and " << *(++diiter);
 cout << " at " << distance(di.begin(), diiter)+1;
 cout << endl;
```

**[This](http://ideone.com/2Bobo)** works well & outputs the correct/desired output.

Comment: Is there a way to put them in just one line? I know putting them on separate lines would work but it looks ugly and I'm still not clear about order of evaluation being unspecified. could you give me more pointer about this? does it related to temporary variable involved (++diter)?

Comment: @Stack Overeem: Please refer the link to another Q I posted in the Answer, It explains the problem well in detail.

Comment: @Stack `++diiter` is indeed the problem. `diiter + 1` will [work](http://ideone.com/WsElA) but relies on the fact that it's a random-access iterator; you can use `std::next(diiter)` with C++0x instead (if not using C++0x you can roll your own `next`).